# Custom use of count function in ms access

Tags: database, ms-access

I have two tables `Patient_tbl` and `Consult_tbl` in MS access (with the fields shown below). The first one is used to record patient info, and the second one (`Consult_tbl`) is used to record patient visits. They are related in a one-to-many relationship using a `Patient_id` field.

What I need to do is to count the visitors based on gender for a given period of time, based on the consult table using `Patient_id`. I don’t know how to do it. Would you please help?

*Patient_tbl* has the following fields:

> {Patient_id
>   P_add
>   P_tel
>   P_gender
>   Other fields}

`Consult_tbl` has the following fields:

> {Consult_id
>   Patient_id
>   C_date
>   C_ref
>   Other fields}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join the tables on Patient_id, add a where clause for the date range and use the count() function and group by P_gender:

```
select p.P_gender, count(*) as "count"
from Patient_tbl p
inner join Consult_tbl c on p.Patient_id = c.Patient_id
where c.C_date >= '2015-01-10' 
  and c.C_date <= '2015-01-20'
group by p.P_gender
```

Comment: Thanks a million @jpw your answer is a bulls eye. Could you please guide me to where to read about SQL codes like what you've done.

Comment: @HayderAl-Qarawee It's a pretty basic query; any good tutorial should cover the concepts. http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SQL_Tutorial is one